# How to convert time stamp format in Python from dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss:msmsms to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:msmsmsmsmsms

Tags: python, database, automation, timestamp, format

I have created an automated data client that pulls data from a txt file and inputs it into a csv file. Each data entry contains a timestamp, but it is not in the format I need it in, I need it to match the datetime.now() format:

**ORIGINAL FORMAT**
[03/11/22 01:06:09:190]

**DESIRED FORMAT**
2022-11-03 01:06:09.190000

I am currently using the following code to pull the timestamp from each line of data I need:

```
82:  reTimestamp = r'\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}'

108: timestamp = re.findall(reTimestamp, line.strip())

110: print(timestamp)

-----------------------------
Output: ['03/11/22 01:05:06:172']
```

Every function is working well up until now because im having trouble converting this timestamp to the desired format. I would also like to get rid of the square brackets '[]'

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the datetime.datetime.strptime() and datetime.datetime.stftime() function:

```
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_string, format="%d/%m%/%y %H:%M:%S.%f")
date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

For more info on the format string check out the documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes